# JQuery и одинаковые имена

Tags: jquery

```
<div class="progress-bar-item-with-text">
                    <p>Количество сделок продажа</p>
                    <div class="progress-bar-item uk-margin-right">
                        <div class="progress-bar-activity" style="width: 10%">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="uk-margin-remove-left uk-child-width-1-2@m" uk-grid>
                        <span class="progress-bar-text-down uk-text-right">1</span>
                        <span class="progress-bar-text-down uk-text-right"><b>1.2</b></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

У меня есть 6 штук блоков, каждые называются одинаково, только значения в теге  `<b>1.2</b>` разные. Как сделать так, чтобы при значении в теге b > 1 к строке

```
<div class="progress-bar-activity" style="width: 10%"></div>
```

добавлялся один класс, а при значении в теге b < 1 добавлялся другой класс?

Делаю так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (parseFloat($('.progress-bar-item-with-text .progress-bar-text-down b').text()) > 1) {
        $('.progress-bar-item-with-text .progress-bar-item .progress-bar-activity').addClass("progress-bar-activity-more");
    }
    else {
        $('.progress-bar-item-with-text .progress-bar-item .progress-bar-activity').addClass("progress-bar-activity-less");
    }
});
```

Но, получается, что один класс добавляется ко всем классами `<div class="progress-bar-activity" style="width: 10%"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо было еще добавить высоту `height` к блоку чтобы было видно.

Если номер больше один будет показывать красный цвет иначе пурпурный.

```js
$(document).ready(_ => {
    document.querySelectorAll(".progress-bar-text-down b").forEach(el => {
        if(el.innerHTML > 1){
             el
              .closest(".progress-bar-item-with-text")
              .querySelector(".progress-bar-activity")
              .classList.add("progress-bar-activity-more");
        }  else {
             el
              .closest(".progress-bar-item-with-text")
              .querySelector(".progress-bar-activity")
              .classList.add("progress-bar-activity-less");
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.progress-bar-activity-more {
  background:red;
}
.progress-bar-activity-less {
  background:purple;
}
.progress-bar-activity {
  height:10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar-item-with-text">
    <p>Количество сделок продажа</p>
    <div class="progress-bar-item uk-margin-right">
        <div class="progress-bar-activity" style="width: 10%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin-remove-left uk-child-width-1-2@m" uk-grid>
        <span class="progress-bar-text-down uk-text-right">1</span>
        <span class="progress-bar-text-down uk-text-right"><b>2</b></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar-item-with-text">
    <p>Количество сделок продажа</p>
    <div class="progress-bar-item uk-margin-right">
        <div class="progress-bar-activity" style="width: 10%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin-remove-left uk-child-width-1-2@m" uk-grid>
        <span class="progress-bar-text-down uk-text-right">1</span>
        <span class="progress-bar-text-down uk-text-right"><b>0</b></span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="progress-bar-item-with-text">
    <p>Количество сделок продажа</p>
    <div class="progress-bar-item uk-margin-right">
        <div class="progress-bar-activity" style="width: 10%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin-remove-left uk-child-width-1-2@m" uk-grid>
        <span class="progress-bar-text-down uk-text-right">1</span>
        <span class="progress-bar-text-down uk-text-right"><b>0</b></span>
    </div>
</div><div class="progress-bar-item-with-text">
    <p>Количество сделок продажа</p>
    <div class="progress-bar-item uk-margin-right">
        <div class="progress-bar-activity" style="width: 10%">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin-remove-left uk-child-width-1-2@m" uk-grid>
        <span class="progress-bar-text-down uk-text-right">1</span>
        <span class="progress-bar-text-down uk-text-right"><b>1.2</b></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Думаю правильнее будет использовать `>0`.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 так у него условия   <<Как сделать так, чтобы при значении в теге b > 1 к строке>>

Comment: да, но мне что-то подсказывает, что `1` и `-1` тоже должны "выделяться"

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 лень менять  )

Comment: Да думаю не стоит, мой комментарий больше для автора вопроса подойдёт)

Comment: Я понял вас ребят, спасибо большое! Щас буду пробовать)

Comment: @ВикторТюрин если ответ помог не забудьте его принять нажав на галочку внизу ответа.

Comment: А вот еще, у меня таких блоков 6 штук. И тогда решение не получается(

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов пробую, если в теге b значение больше 1, то все блоки становятся такого же цвета как у него

Comment: @Виктор Тюрин я сейчас не за компьютером. Дополню  свой ответ через два три часа  и напишу вам сюда.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов благодарю!

Comment: @ВикторТюрин я обновил ответ написал на Js надеюсь с этим проблем не будет у вас .

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов спасибо! Разобрался

Comment: @ВикторТюрин всегда пожалуйста.